# Is there some kind of tool to look at the encoding of Intel x86 instructions?

Tags: encoding, x86

Forgive me if this might be a dumb question but, I'm in an assembly class that was mostly taught using an emulated CPU that was supposed to teach the concepts of assembly code. We haven't even written an Intel program, so I'm trying to adjust. In our emulated CPU, we were able to generate a symbol table file that gave the bytes equivalent for instructions:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIKP5.png

Would I be able to do such a thing with Intel x86 instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [IDA.](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) It has an option to show binary values of opcodes.

EDIT: Well.. it's a disassembler. Try opening a binary file, and set the number of opcode bytes to show (in Options/General/)  to something that is not zero.

If you are looking for an IDE that shows you in real time the opcodes for the instruction you've used, then I don't think you'll find one, because of lack of "market". Can you explain why you need it? Do you want to know just their length, or want to learn them? There is simple pattern for lengths, so by dissasembling many binaries you'll catch it. If it's the opcodes you want.. well, there are lots of them, almost no rules, and practically no use to do it.

I see.. then you have to generate the *list file* . Your assembler should have an option for that. (for NASM it's `-l listfile`). Just put any instruction(s) in your .asm file, and generate listing for it. It should contain the binary encoding for each instruction.

First, get [Intel Instruction Set Refference](http://www.intel.com/design/pentiumii/manuals/243191.htm), or, better, this link: http://siyobik.info/index.php?module=x86 . There you'll find that most opcodes have several encodings. In your particular case, the bit 1 of the opcode specifies direction, and since both operands are registers, you can toggle the direction and swap the register codes, and the result will be the same. Usually you have this freedom on most register to register arithmetic operations. To check this, try decompiling with IDA this source file:

```
db 02h, E0h
db 00h, C4h
```

Comment: would you perhaps be able to point me to the right direction? I opened the .asm file with the program, but I have no idea where to go next.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me already. Again I should re-emphasize my teacher hasn't really taught us how to write a complete program in Intel, and all we've really covered are concepts such as addressing modes and what not. The way our emulated cpu worked was it took the code and generated the symbol table file and an obj file which was executed.

Comment: Basically we're supposed to deduce how an instruction would be encoded. I'm looking at the rules and what not, but I want to be sure that I'm following them right. (ie the different opcodes of MOV, depending upon 8bit registers/memory vs 16bit, addressing modes etc). If there aren't those types of things available, then I guess I'l just have to hope I'm reading it right. Thanks though.

Comment: Thanks I got the listfile generated, but for some reason it isn't giving me what I am expecting. for ADD AH,AL it gives me 00C4. 

My book says for 8086, ADD has a $02 opcode for 8bit registers/memory, a mod of 11 (binary) to use a register instead of a memory address, AH is 100 (binary), AL is 000 (binary). 1110 0000 binary is $E0.

So all together the entire instruction would be $02E0. If you would be so kind as to explain the difference?

Answer (score 1):

There is a demo program shipped with [fasm.dll](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=6239) which has an editor and hex-viewer: [image]